# Python entry point via ssh not found

Tags: python, ssh, entry-point

I created a Python package which has 1 entry point under `console_scripts`. It works fine when the package is installed and I'm calling the command in the machine's own bash.

However, when the command is called from from outside via `ssh`, it fails.

If I run this command:

```
ssh host "command1"
```

... I get this error:

> bash: command1: command not found

But when running from the host machine, it works fine. Any clues?

Comment: Could the account you're using have something to do with it? What's in one account's path might not be in another's.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy the account I installed and tested with is the same I use to do ssh. So no apparent difference there I'd say.

Comment: When you test it from the command-line, do you call it using `command1` or `./command1`, or something else?

Comment: @cdarke `command1`. It's a a console script entry point, it's supposed to behave like a command, not like a script.